# The operation is insecure in React using MQTT package from npm

Tags: reactjs, mqtt, create-react-app

I have a little app that gets sensor data and i want to use mqtt to distribute them. I've found this package on npm called MQTT, with this i can make a client in the browser, if i'm using an http insecure connection it works fine but when i use https i get an error in the create-react-app development server saying that this:

```
this.client = mqtt.connect();
```

It's an **'Insecure operation'**, someone had this problem or know any solution?

Also, in the wiki there is not an entry for a secure connection or something similar.

EDIT: the component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import mqtt from 'mqtt'

class MqttComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.client = mqtt.connect();

        this.client.on('connect', () => {
            console.log(`connected`);

        })

        this.client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
            let payload = JSON.parse(message);
            let payloadKey = topic.substring(1);
            console.log('message');
            this.props.actualizarPorMensaje(payload, payloadKey);
        });
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        Object.keys(this.props.equipos)
            .filter(numeroSerie => !(numeroSerie in prevProps.equipos))
            .map(numeroSerie => (
                this.client.subscribe(`/${numeroSerie}`)
            )
        );
    }

    render() {
        return;
    }
}

export default MqttComponent;
```

Comment: There isn't really enough information here for us to help, show more of the code you have used to set up the MQTT client.

Comment: There isn't more really, it's just the import on the top of a functional component